# Windows 11 Blocking Google Services?

Tags: networking, google-chrome

**Problem:** My Windows 11 PC seems to be blocking access to Google services, including Google Bard and Google Fi Sync (sync for messages and voicemails to web). I've tried various troubleshooting steps, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I say that this issue is on my PC only because I can access the sites from different PCs and phones.

**Symptoms:**

- Bard endlessly loads, and nothing happens.
- Fi Sync displays a blank page when I access it on my PC.

**What I've Tried So Far:**

- Checked the hosts file (it's default with no entries that should block Google).
- Flushed the DNS cache.
- Checked proxy settings (automatic proxy detection is enabled).
- Disabled Windows Defender Firewall temporarily.
- Tested multiple web browsers (Chrome and Edge) with no success.
- Verified that Google services work on other devices using the same network.

**Additional Information:**

- Windows 11 OS.
- Chrome is my default browser. However, didn’t work when testing on Edge either.
- I don't have any third-party security software installed.
- My network connection appears to be stable.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on what I can try next, please let me know. I'd greatly appreciate any help or insights you can provide.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Windows 11 that I can see (using Windows 11 Pro). Try a TCP / IP Reset and restart .    Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer and then test

Comment: `multiple web browsers (Chrome and Edge)` that's basically the same pig with different lipstick. Try an actually *different* browser like Firefox (though, in this case, probably won't make any difference)